# Не работают сигналы и слоты QWebSocket в отдельном потоке

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, websocket

Имею метод:

```
void WebSocketWorker::connectSocket()
{
    _webSocket = new QWebSocket();
    connect(_webSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(onConnected()) ); //, Qt::QueuedConnection
    connect(_webSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onDisconnected()) );
    connect(_webSocket, SIGNAL(textMessageReceived(const QString&)),
            this, SLOT(onTextMessageReceived(const QString&)) );

    _webSocket->open(QUrl("ws://неважно"));
}
```

если запускаю в главном потоке программы, например так:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    WebSocketWorker worker;
    worker.process(); // <== connectSocket() запускается внутри

    return a.exec();
}
```

то все слоты (`onConnected`, `onDisconnected`, `onTextMessageReceived`) прекрасно запускаются на соотверствующие события.
Как только запускаю в отдельном потоке (в соответствии с [документацией](https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage)):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThread *thread = new QThread;
    Worker *worker = new WebSocketWorker();
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
    QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    //connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(onThreadFinished()));
    thread->start();

    //while(1);//block the thread

    return a.exec();
}
```

Все, перестает запускать слоты. Что за загадка?

**Дополнение:**
Все таки проблема в QWebSocket, а не в сигналах-слотах вообще. Приконнектил в connectSocket свой класс:

```
void WebSocketWorker::connectSocket()
{
    _some = new SomeClass();
    connect(_some, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(onConnected()), Qt::QueuedConnection );

    _some->open();
}
```

и прекрасно отзывается (я делаю `emit` в `SomeClass::open()`)

Нашел похожую проблему ([бам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856216/qwebsockets-wont-work-in-threads)), но рецепт с

```
qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractSocket::SocketState>();
```

не помог

## **Исходники**

Worker.h

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker();

signals:
    void finished();
    void error(QString err);
public slots:
    void process();
    void onThreadFinished();

protected:
    virtual void processVirtual() = 0;
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

==========================================
Worker.cpp

```
#include "Worker.h"
#include <QDebug>

Worker::Worker() : QObject()
{

}

void Worker::process()
{
    processVirtual();
    emit finished();
}

void Worker::onThreadFinished()
{
    qDebug() << "Что такое?";
    deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: а не работает, когда раскомментирована строка `while(1);` ?

Comment: нет, не работает при while(1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл проблему в Вашем коде. Всё довольно просто, у Вас есть следующий `connect`:

```
QObject::connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
```

Сигнал `finished()` испускается сразу по завершении `processVirtual`:

```
processVirtual();
emit finished();
```

Ну а `processVirtual` завершается сразу по завершении `connectSocket`, который закрывается довольно быстро, т.к. судя по всему интерфейс `QWebSocket` является асинхронным(я не знаком с этим классом и в документации я этого не вижу, но на практике `open` завершается мгновенно). Поэтому и получается, что поток закрывается не успев получить ответ от сервера.

Comment: сам process() запускается, не запускаются слоты, соедененные внутри него; причем только для QWebSocket, для других классов от QObject и они запускаются (см. дополнение к вопросу)

Comment: не равнозначен ли запуск QMetaObject::invokeMethod(worker, "process"); простому worker-> process()? Но тогда это будет просто запуск в основном потоке. Но суть моего вопроса в том, чтобы запустить WebSocket в отдельном потоке! Может я неправильно понял ваш ответ? Тогда прошу работающий пример и я дам + и отмечу принятым

Comment: чтоб прекратить споры (хоть и не вижу в этом смысла): запустил QMetaObject::invokeMethod(worker, "process"); сразу после  thread->start();, ничего хорошего не получилось. Попробуйте дать пример работующего кода, так как из совета не видно как и где следует это вызывать

Comment: могу выслать zip-ом. Мой адрес asianirish@gmail.com

Comment: да, отправил, и опубликовал прямо в вопросе

Comment: Должен сработать слот onDisconect

Comment: Или можно найти общедоступный ws сервен (как доеду до дому найду).

Comment: Но тут суть в  том, что пример SomeClass  работает, то есть тут не общая проблема с thread, а частная c qwebsocket

Comment: Да, действительно, все очень просто, как это я не заметил? :) Огромное спасибо!